# Object at index in NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, arrays

I have an array. I want to check whether there is an object present in a particular index or not. How to do this? Please help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check whether a **specific object** exists at a particular index or whether **any object** exists at a particular index?

Comment: @gtm I want to check any object at a specific index. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

if you just want to check if there is an object

```
if (myIndex < [array count])
```

if you want to find a specific object

```
[array indexOfObject:myObject];
```

if you want to know if the object at some index is of some class

```
[[array objectAtIndex:myIndex] isKindOfClass:[TheClassToCompareTo class]];
```

Comment: From the reference: If index is beyond the end of the array (that is, if index is greater than or equal to the value returned by count), an NSRangeException is raised.

Comment: `NSArray` cannot contain `nil`.

Answer (score 11):

`BOOL exists = index < [array count] ? YES : NO;`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `containsObject` method to check weather your array contains the specific object or not. If contains, then get its index by `indexOfObject` method

```
if ([yourArrayArray containsObject:yourObject]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Found");
    int index = [yourArray indexOfObject:yourObject];     
}
```

Comment: You can also remove the `-[NSArray containsObject:]` line and instead check whether `-[NSArray indexOfObject:]` returned `NSNotFound` or not.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old thread but just trying to help.

You can add a category to `NSArray` something like this

```
@implementation NSArray (Safe)

- (id)safeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index >= [self count]) return nil;
    return [self objectAtIndex:index];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

check like this

```
if([array objectAtIndex:i]!= nil)
{
NSLog("Object present");
}
else{
NSLog("Object Not Present")
}
```

Modified:
You should make like this

```
if(i<=[array count]){
    if([array objectAtIndex:i]!= nil)
    {
    NSLog("Object present");
    }
    else{
    NSLog("Object Not Present")
    }
}
```

This will not raise exception and object in array should compare with nil value

Comment: if you check for objects you check against nil and not null

Comment: From the reference: If index is beyond the end of the array (that is, if index is greater than or equal to the value returned by count), an NSRangeException is raised.

Comment: you can use `nil`..
so you can use [array count] for counting the array element and use if condition

Comment: Nope; firstly `objectAtIndex` will raise an exception as described in my first comment, and `NSArray` cannot contain `nil` so that won't work either.

Comment: Again, `NSArray` cannot contain `nil` also `<=` is wrong it needs to be `<`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the length of the array (using the `count` method) and given `NSArray` cannot contain `nil` it must therefore contain *something*:

```
- (BOOL)arrayContainsSomethingAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index
{
    return [_myArray count] > index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must check if the index of that object is smaller than the size of the array, then you query the array at that index.

```
if (index < [array count] && [array objetAtIndex:index]){
/* Your code*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [indexOfObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html) method.

```
if ([Array indexOfObject:object]==index) {
        //code
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean `if([Array indexOfObject:obj] == index)`?